# Unable to find element using Xpath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Click on the element for the below HTML code is not working.

```
a class="add" href="/travelPlan_revamp/addTravel.htm?travel_type=D">Add</a>
```

I'm using the next **Xpath:** `html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/a`

But `No Such Element Found` exception is displayed.

Comment: Be sure that the element is not inside an iframe. Xpath can be obtained with Firebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry guys the the thing is it was in Iframe. Now i have found the solution by switching to the iframe and then clicking an event.

driver.switchTo().frame("rightMenu");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/a")).click();

Answer (score 1):

First make sure the web element is not inside iframe.
If yes, Then you need to switch to iframe first and then try clicking on element.

Also, try below xpath, in case you have captured wrong xpath:-

> //a[@class='add' and .='Add']

Answer (score 1):

An absolute xpath always starts with a forward slash '/'. I think you have used an absolute xpath and either you have missed'/' or you quoted it wrong here. Please verify it. Normally absolute xpath will look like /html/body/form/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/input

Answer (score 1):

Try this xpath:

```
 //a[contains(text(),'Add')];
```

Comment: Error again
 org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression  //a[contains(text(),'Add')] because of the following error:
TypeError: Failed to execute 'createNSResolver' on 'Document': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell if your XPATH expression is right without the HTML.
Your XPATH expression tell:

- Take a "a" elements
- In the 2nd div element
- In the first div element
- In the body element
- That is in the html element

So checks there is a "a" element that check the Xpath expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
//a[@class='add' and text()='Add']
```

Try that one.

Through which method are you looking for the element?

```
@FindBy (how = How.XPATH)
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath());
```

Sometimes the @FindBy notation doesn't like working with Xpaths properly.

Comment: I have used driver.findElement(By.xpath());. Still it is displaying the error

Comment: Just to make sure, you are ensuring the page is loaded before trying to find the element? Could you share the code snippet looking for element? Not surr that the issue lies with the xpath if you have provided correct html, as one of the many solutions should work

Comment: If you have resolved you issue can you close it and mark an answer, otherwise would you be able to provide more information so we can better tackle the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this below xpath

//a[contains(text(),'Add')]

Comment: Error again org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //a[contains(text(),'Add')] because of the following error: TypeError: Failed to execute 'createNSResolver' on 'Document': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.